# How do I copy a url from a website to a word 2010 document as a hyperlink with the blue, underlined text?

Tags: microsoft-word-2010, hyperlink

How do I copy a url from a website to a word 2010 document as a hyperlink showing the blue, underlined text? I am not getting the option to paste and keep the source formatting, only to paste text.

Comment: Can you tell us which browser?

Comment: Microsoft Edge.  I have tried Chrome and Internet Explorer but it makes no difference.  This is only a problem in Word, and a new problem as for January and most of February I had this functionality; however since my initial post this functionality has been lost. In Excel I am have this functionality.

Answer (score 4):

- Typically you just paste the link and press <kbd>Enter</kbd> or <kbd>Space</kbd> and **AutoCorrect will automatically convert it into a link for you**. If it didn't work then possibly you've [turned off auto correction](https://www.howtogeek.com/363265/update-how-to-disable-automatic-hyperlinks-in-microsoft-word/).

  You can turn it on again by clicking *File > Word options > Proofing > AutoCorrect > AutoFormat/AutoFormat As You Type* and check ***Internet and network paths with hyperlinks***

  [image: AutoCorrect for hyperlink]

  [image: AutoCorrect 2]
- Alternatively just type/paste the text you want to display as a link, select it and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd> then paste the link. Or select `Insert > Hyperlink`. This way you have more control over the link

  [image: Insert Hyperlink]

Answer (score 0):

Use Excel to do a little help:

For example, there is text, https://superuser.com. In Excel, key in formula

```
=HYPERLINK("https://superuser.com")
```

and it produces the text in hyperlink format.

Copy and paste it/them into Word.

Comment: that seems overkill just to get a hyperlink

Comment: more importantly your smart quotes `“”` will cause problems because Excel doesn't understand it